# How bad is nested components in terms of performance and rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This question may seem very simple, although it involves a deeper understanding of the basics of react. Basically, I came up with this situation with some coworkers during a project:

Let's assume a very simple situation (as shown on react docs page https://react.dev/learn/understanding-your-ui-as-a-tree)

InspirationGenerator.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import inspirations from './inspirations';
import FancyText from './FancyText';
import Color from './Color';

export default function InspirationGenerator({children}) {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const inspiration = inspirations[index];
  const next = () => setIndex((index + 1) % inspirations.length);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Your inspirational {inspiration.type} is:</p>
      {inspiration.type === 'quote'
      ? <FancyText text={inspiration.value} />
      : <Color value={inspiration.value} />}

      <button onClick={next}>Inspire me again</button>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

FancyText.js

```
export default function FancyText({title, text}) {
  return title
    ? <h1 className='fancy title'>{text}</h1>
    : <h3 className='fancy cursive'>{text}</h3>
}
```

This example shows the relationship between parent and child components by importing files, but a while ago we took the approach of simplifying the code and reducing the number of files, and started putting components inside other components.

An example based on the above scenario would be as follows:

InspirationGenerator.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import inspirations from './inspirations';
import FancyText from './FancyText';
import Color from './Color';

export default function InspirationGenerator({children}) {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const inspiration = inspirations[index];
  const next = () => setIndex((index + 1) % inspirations.length);

  const Content = () =>{
    if(inspiration.type === "quote"){
       return <div>Some random text</div>
    }
    if(inspiration.type === "color"){
       return <div>Some random color </div>
    }
    return null
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>Your inspirational {inspiration.type} is:</p>
      
      <Content />

      <button onClick={next}>Inspire me again</button>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

At first this approach seemed very good and could deal with various scenarios where a component returns a view based on simple if/else checks and avoids duplicated code in some scenarios.

The problem is that we started to realize that this approach, although it seems promising, sometimes brings side effects and strange renders, last week I solved two problems that were precisely this issue, and by placing them in a separate file they worked normally. I tried some react strategies to overcome the problem, like using React.useMemo to avoid render issues and it didn't work well.

So we discussed it as a team and we have divergent opinions on this, I say that whenever there is a child component we can never use it this way (we should always use another file and import it) and my colleague says that if the scenario is very simple we can use nested components to make the code cleaner.

So, how bad is "internal nested components" practice?
Should we always create separate files for components, or it will lead to a perfomance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we started putting components inside other components

Yeah, absolutely **never** do that!

On every render of the parent component, a *new* function is created, and React will recognise that as a different component. It will unmount the old component instance and mount a new instance. This is not necessarily a performance problem (it might, or it might not), but is an absolute nightmare if the inner component attempts to use hooks. Those just won't work.

Instead, you can

- place the component next to the main component in the same file, just don't export it

  ```
  function Content({ inspiration }) {
    if (inspiration.type === "quote") {
      return <div>Some random text</div>
    }
    …
    return null
  }

  export default function InspirationGenerator({children}) {
    …
    return (
      <>
        …
        <Content inspiration={inspiration} />
        …
        {children}
      </>
    );
  }
  ```
- make it a nested helper function that you *call*, instead of rendering it as a component

  ```
  export default function InspirationGenerator({children}) {
    …
    const getContent = () => {
      if (inspiration.type === "quote") {
        return <div>Some random text</div>
      }
      …
      return null
    }
    return (
      <>
        …
        {getContent()}
        …
        {children}
      </>
    );
  }
  ```
- use an IIFE, `useMemo`, or similar expression, to build the value that you render

  ```
  export default function InspirationGenerator({children}) {
    …
    const content = (() => {
      if (inspiration.type === "quote") {
        return <div>Some random text</div>
      }
      …
      return null
    })();
    return (
      <>
        …
        {content}
        …
        {children}
      </>
    );
  }
  ```